# Azure network security group (NSG) not respecting rule

Tags: azure, networking

I have a kubernetes cluster with an nginx server deployed, and bound to a public IP via a loadbalancer.
Additionally I have a domain, which points to the public IP.

All traffic to the kubernetes nodes flows through a network security group, with the following rules, but my own ip has been changed to 8.8.8.8:

| Priority | Name | port | protocol | source | destination | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | AllowAllIngress | Any | Any | Any | 8.8.8.8 | Allow |
| 1000 | DenyAllInbound | Any | Any | Internet | Any | Deny |

## expectation

I would expect that if I access the ip address or the domain name pointing to it, that it would work

## reality

I cannot connect to the ip. If I change rule 1000 to allow, it works. If i change rule 1000 back to deny, it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using the second rule, as there already is a default rule to reject all that has not been opened like this:

| Priority | Name | port | protocol | source | destination | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900 | AllowAllIngress | Any | Any | Any | 8.8.8.8 | Allow |
| 65500 | DenyAllInbound | Any | Any | Any | Any | Deny |

I have not managed to fix the issue that arises with rule 1000, if I add the rule it breaks, but logically the default rule already denies all access.